# How to pass the value to the href attribute and target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I did the following jquery script. I was trying to open this url in a new tab but with this doesn't work on internet explorer. How do I pass the value to the button so I can open in a new tab?

```js
var checkSurl = "<%=checkSURL%>";
        var iframeDetalleSOnLoad = function(obj) {
            $(obj).show();
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#detalleS").html("");

            $("[name=buscar]").on("click", function() {
                var bottonBuscar = $(this);


                var numS = $("#numS");
                if (numS.val() == "") {
                    alert("El numero de s no puede estar vacestar vacío");
                }
                else {
                    // Call per verifica existence of s
                    $.ajax({
                        url: checkSurl + "?numS=" + $("#numS").val(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            var isS = eval(response.trim());
                            console.log(isS);

                            // returns che il s esiste
                            if (isS) {
                                var targetURL = "https://www.sample.es/cgi-bin/fccgi.exe?w3exec=DET&CONTROL=samole&ID=" + numS.val();
                                bottonBuscar.parent('a').attr('href',targetURL);
                                bottonBuscar.parent('a').attr('target', '_blank');
                                console.log(bottonBuscar.parent('a').attr('href',targetURL));
                                console.log(bottonBuscar.parent('a').attr('target', '_blank'));

                            }
                            else {
                                alert("EL NUMERO DE S QUE HA INSERTADO NO ES CORRECTO.");
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            $("#detalleS").html(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

the html element where I wanted to change is the href and probably to set the target to '_blank'.

```html
<div class="formulario" >
                        <div align="center">
                            <a href="#"
                               onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"
                               onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('buscar','','<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/buttonBuscarEnvio_over.png',1)">
                                <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/buttonBuscarEnvio.png" alt="Buscar S"
                                     name="buscar" border="0" id="buscar"></a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Main issue here is that you've included `console.log()` function and Internet Explorer will throw an error so the subsequent scripts will not work after the `console.log()` call. so you could try removing them...

remove the three `console.log('...')` calls that is in the code snippet you've provided... that should do it...

or you could use it like `window.console && window.console.log('text')`

It seems your goal is to open the url in new tab or new window whenever the image with name="buscar" is clicked...

in that case, I'd recommend replacing the $.ajax block with this

```
                   $.ajax({
                    url: checkSurl + "?numS=" + $("#numS").val(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        var isS = eval(response.trim());

                        // returns che il s esiste
                        if (isS) {
                            var targetURL = "https://www.sample.es/cgi-bin/fccgi.exe?w3exec=DET&CONTROL=samole&ID=" + numS.val();
                            window.open(targetURL, "_blank");

                        }
                        else {
                            alert("EL NUMERO DE S QUE HA INSERTADO NO ES CORRECTO.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        $("#detalleS").html(error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thank you. Already solved instead of window.open(targetURL, "_blank"); I wrote: oNewWindow = window.open(targetURL); the console.log() were not a problem